# Stored Procedure execution is very slow

Tags: stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure which returns multiple result sets and takes a lot of time to execute. I have to bind these result sets to the controls at the front end side. But it also takes a lot of time to display the results and there is no option of changing the stored procedures. So what else can I try?

```
Here is my stored proc,

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getdata] 
@Week int = 1,
@Year int = 2014
AS
BEGIN
declare @current_week int
set @current_week = datepart (week, getdate()) 
while @Week <= @current_week
begin
exec SP_GetResults_New @Week,@Year
set @Week = @Week + 1
end
END

Thanks.
```

Comment: If the stored procedures you can't change are what's slow, can you change any of the tables and indexes they use? Do you know how much time is taken in display, and how much executing the stored procs? What database product are you using?

Comment: @hatchet It takes around 3 mins to display the results. I can't change the tables also and I am developing a kendo mobile application.